# Filter content with regex PB with accent

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, regex

I try to filter the items displaying thanks to 2 input fields.

There is my filter function : I built my two regex, then I hide content and then I filter with the first field value (e) and then I filter the result with the second (e2).

```
function filterFolder(e,e2) {
    var regex = new RegExp(e,"u");
    var regex2 = new RegExp(e2,"u");
    jQuery('.size').hide();
    var un=$('.size').filter(function () {
        return regex.test($(this).data('dossier'))
    });
 var deux=un.filter(function () {
        return regex2.test($(this).data('fichier'))
    });
    deux.show();
}
```

There is a sample of html filtred element :

```
<li class="size " data-dossier="one of filter with éee" data-fichier="the other filter with é">some content</li>
```

This filter is working fine with static generate HTML (i write it manually in my html file). But when I construct the content with my AJAX request it's doesn't work.

There is my ajax call :

```
jQuery.post("scanVisu.php",
  {contentType: "text/html;charset=UTF-8"
}) .done(function( value ) {
    $("#scanFold").html(value);

      });
```

And the header of my PHP script :

```
 header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

So there is a problem in the relation between my JS function in my PHP generated content but i don't know what.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the value you pass to the function?

Comment: It's an input field from the user : so it can be everything for test i use é character but it don't work.

Comment: No idea, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/heoef804/) it works.

Comment: Please do not include the JQuery part if your issue is regex. RegExp is part of the JavaScript language, not part of JQuery. Please provide exact input string, exact pattern and how you define it, and expected behavior. A plunkr/fiddle is also welcome.

Comment: BTW, `RegExp#test()` cannot return nothing: it returns either true or false.